# parsing javascript array object to create new javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My sample `javascript` array format which I get from **server**:

```
var json =[
{
    "id": "1",
    "tagName": [
        {
            "fruit": "apple"
        },
        {
            "fruit": "watermelon"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "tagName": [
        {
            "fruit": "orange"
        },
        {
            "fruit": "pineapple"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "tagName": [
        {
            "fruit": "banana"
        },
        {
            "fruit": "guava"
        }
    ]
}
```

];

I need to create a javascript function which will generate an array from the above array which will be like this

```
var json1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

AND

```
var json1a = [{ "id": "1" }, { "id": "2" }, { "id":"3" }]
```

All help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the attempts you've made to solve this yourself

Comment: That's not valid JSON, nor javascript ?

Comment: @adeneo : valid json now..

Comment: @Arnab http://jsfiddle.net/tujydk9L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to iterate through the array:

```
var json1 = [];
var json1a = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
    json1.push(json[i].id);
    json1a.push({id: json[i].id});   
}
```

If I may advise, you IDs should be Numbers, instead of strings. In this case, you would use:

```
json1.push(json[i].id);
json1a.push({"id", json[i].id});
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tujydk9L/7/).

Comment: OP will have big issues trying to parse his JSON, as it's not valid.

Comment: @meskobalazs sorry, my actual json is far complex, was in hurry to create a simple json, thanks for ur answer, chking now..

Comment: Updated your fiddle, both you and I did a typo.